# Codeblocks won't compile exe files in Linux using GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks, cross-compiling, sdl-2

I'm trying to compile an `exe` program on Linux, using code blocks GNU GCC, because the includes and C++17 and all sorts of things are much harder on windows (my windows version doesn't allow msys2 for C++17, which I need for my project). In my program, I am using `SDL2` and have the `Other linker options` added for it on `Codeblocks`, also, the search directories of: **Compiler** `/usr/include` and **Linker** `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. For toolchain executables, they go in the order of:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
x86_64-w64-mingw32-ar
debugger.....
x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres
make
```

I have also run the commands such as:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev:i386
```

But now, when (AFTER DELETING OBJ FILES), there are about 50+ errors,    starting with:    `/usr/include/stdint.h   conflicting declaration 'typedef long unsigned int uintptr_t'` and alot more, but that is just for a start,

Here is the code (smallest scale code that won't compile):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you post the code too?

Comment: @AndreiRagman added it to question

Comment: Here's the problem though, I *can* compile that code and get an exe file, but that is through the command line. I don't know how to compile Multiple files of a project and the SDL2 includes and etc with the command line, thats why i use codeblocks, but it won't work with codeblocks

Comment: *"don't know how to compile Multiple files"* It's as easy as `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ 1.cpp 2.cpp 3.cpp`.

Comment: oh ok. Is there a better way? If theres like 20+ files, also with ```.h``` files? And doing that will work with having 1 ```main.cpp``` file, compiling all other files will be added to the ```main.cpp```?

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have worded that better. Say I have a project of 20+ ```.cpp``` and ```.h``` files, one of which is my ```main.cpp``` where my ```int main()``` lies. Is there a way to do it other than writing out every single file? Like the directory and the file extensions or something? Also, if there isn't, will compiling the ```.cpp``` also work with the header files too? @HolyBlackCat

Comment: Oh, and also, with my ```SDL2``` includes, I don't know how to command-line compile to include them. Keeps giving me "no such file or directory"

Comment: If you don't want to type that manually, consider using a *build system*: `make` and `cmake` are quite popular. Can't help you with the includes though; there's a way to specify the directory where they are, but you need to find that directory.

Comment: Oh, okay. If, say on my codeblocks, I have my search directories for my includes and lib files, how would I do the same for compiling through command line so that it has no problem with "no such file or directory found for SDL2", and i type in something like, ```x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ main.cpp``` where it has the optimization flags, ```C++17```, ```warnings```, ```errors``` etc that codeblocks shows that makes debugging easier? @HolyBlackCat

Comment: as in, use the search directories to find SDL2 when compiling  through command line for example. Also, the ```-lSDL2  -lSDL2main  -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf```

Comment: `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ 1.cpp 2.cpp -Iinclude_path -Llinker_path -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf`. You `-l...` flags look wrong, so I changed them a bit.

Comment: oh okay, thanks. With that, how do i add ```C++17``` and like ```o3``` optimization flags to it aswell? + warnings and the output ```.exe``` file. Sorry i've never really used command line compiling before @HolyBlackCat

Comment: Google it, those flags aren't very hard to find.

Comment: oh okay, I tried that, the includes for SDL2 worked, but I wrote this in my command line: ```x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ main.cpp -I/usr/include -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf 
``` and it is giving me an error ```/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/corecrt.h:112:24: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef short unsigned int wctype_t’``` @HolyBlackCat

Comment: @GgsgnHdjwngnf you're building with cross-compiler but including your hosts's `stdint.h`. Why? There is no reason to believe it should work. There should be no `-I/usr/include -L/usr/lib/x86_x64-linux-gnu` as these are your host paths, not target's. Check where your targets `stdint.h` is stored and add this path, if default paths doesn't suit your case.